# How can i use click in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, onclick, mouseevent, onclicklistener

```
<input type ="text" name="something" id="something"required (click)="saveData()>
```

I have **input** field like this if the required error is **not there** then only **click** mouse event should work(call).!

how can I do that.?
i am new to angular

I want something like this:

```
 <input type ="text" name="something" id="something"required *ngIf="something.errors == null (click)="saveData() " >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like :

```
(click)="something.errors == null ? saveData() : false"
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-conditional-click)**

---

OR as @PankajParkar's comment

```
(click)="something.errors?.length && saveData()"
```

Comment: Just suggestion `something.errors?.length && saveData()` would sound nicer

Comment: @PankajParkar, Updated the answer with your suggestion , thanks btw

Comment: This is considered bad practice. Write your code in your code and your template in your template. Template should call "onClick" and then code (class) should decide if it should call "saveData" further or not. Your business logic is now inside the template, which is a maintenance nightmare.